# Using tikz overlay / remember picture option with forest trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, trees, forest

I want to connect two forest trees with an arrow, in a similar way it is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58360/how-to-draw-a-joining-line-between-two-picture-tikz-pgf) for plain tikz trees. However, it seems to be impossible to add options to the forest environment in a similar fashion. Simply referencing the nodes will only place the arrow to the right of the right tree. (To avoid confusions: I don't speak about the `$\Rightarrow_G$` in the first forest environment, but the bended one, that should connect two specific nodes.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\false}{\mathbf{f}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{forest}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}  

% Tree 1
\begin{forest}
    [$\sigma$, calign=last
        [$a$]
        [{\langle \sigma, \{1,2\},\false \rangle}% 
                , math content, calign=first, baseline, draw=blue, ellipse,  name = replaceNode
            [$\sigma_*$]
            [$a$]
        ]
    ]
  \node at (current bounding box.east)
        [anchor=west]
        {$\Rightarrow_G$};
\end{forest}
%
% Tree 2
\begin{forest}
    [$\sigma$, calign=last
        [$a$]
        [$\sigma$, calign=last
            [$b$]
            [{\langle \sigma, \{1,2\},\false \rangle}% 
                , math content, calign=first, baseline, name = t1
                [$\sigma$, calign=first
                    [$\sigma_*$]
                    [$a$]
                ]
                [$b$]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
%
% This arrow should connect two nodes of both trees.
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->, black, dashed, bend angle=45, bend left] (replaceNode) to (t1);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

There seems to be the workaround of putting both trees in the same forest environment with a phantom parent node. However, I would appreciate an overlay solution for better modularity of my graphics, especially if more than two trees are involved.

Comment: Interesting question. One can add the `remember picture` option by for example `\forestset{begin draw/.code={\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]}}`, but this ruins the rendering.

Comment: Does `tikzmark` work with `forest`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @cfr suggested in the comment section, this can be done by making use of the `tikzmark` library.

You need to add `\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}` to your preamble. Then, you can put a `\subnode` in each `forest` environment and then add a `tikzpicture` after that with the options `overlay` and `remember picture`.

When you issue the `\draw` command, you can prefix the names of the `subnode`s with `pic cs:`, if you want to treat that `subnode` as a coordinate point (otherwise don't use the `pic cs:` prefix). Note that you will also need to compile the document twice.

I've also moved the starting point and ending point of the arrow up and over a bit by using the `($()+()$)` syntax for specifying a coordinate position.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcommand{\false}{\mathbf{f}}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{forest}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}  

% Tree 1
\begin{forest}
    [$\sigma$, calign=last
        [$a$]
        [\subnode{replaceNode}{$\langle\sigma, \{1,2\},\false \rangle$}, calign=first, baseline, draw=blue, ellipse
            [$\sigma_*$]
            [$a$]
        ]
    ]
  \node at (current bounding box.east)
        [anchor=west]
        {$\Rightarrow_G$};
\end{forest}
%
% Tree 2
\begin{forest}
    [$\sigma$, calign=last
        [$a$]
        [$\sigma$, calign=last
            [$b$]
            [\subnode{t1}{$\langle\sigma, \{1,2\},\false \rangle$}, calign=first, baseline
                [$\sigma$, calign=first
                    [$\sigma_*$]
                    [$a$]
                ]
                [$b$]
            ]
        ]
    ]
\end{forest}
%
% This arrow should connect two nodes of both trees.
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[->, black, dashed, bend angle=45, bend left] ($(pic cs:replaceNode)+(0.25,.2)$) to ($(pic cs:t1)+(0.25,.2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice trees! It does seem ironic that a package named `forest` cannot manage more than one tree without help...

Comment: @cfr Agreed! `:)`