# Connecting two nodes from different forest trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, linguistics, forest

I want to draw the following figure without `pstricks`:

[image]

What I have is the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}   

\usepackage{forest}

\usepackage[external]{adjustbox}


\newcommand{\menge}[1]{%
\mbox{%
$%
\left\{%
\ignorespaces#1%
\right\}%
$%
%\\[-1.5mm]
}%
}


\forestset{
tag/.style={for tree={parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,align=center,base=top}},
% a style that creates an arrow pointing to the substitution node from a tree top node encoded as daughter 
substitution/.style={edge={<-,dashed},l+=\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\menge{
\adjustbox{valign=c}{%
\begin{forest}
tag
[S
        [NP$_1^1\downarrow$]
        [S,name=s1]]
\end{forest}
}
\hspace{1cm}
\adjustbox{valign=c}{%
\begin{forest}
tag
[S,name=s2
        [NP$_1^1$
                [e]]
        [VP
                [NP$_1^2\downarrow$]
                [S*]
                [V$_1$
                        [versprach]]]]
%\draw(s1.south)--(s2.north);
\end{forest}
}
}

\end{document}
```

I think connecting two nodes would be the logically correct way to do this, but the scope of the node naming ends with the `forest` environment, doesn't it. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I think you can find the answer in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174398/using-tikz-overlay-remember-picture-option-with-forest-trees/205097#205097 where a very similar problem is solved. Is it a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, this is true. The bending of the line is different, but I will find out how this is done. Thanks for pointing me to this solution!

Comment: Can we close it as duplicate?

Comment: **Please stop using `minimal` for examples.** As has been pointed out before, it is not appropriate for this purpose.