# Draw connection between node in forest tree diagram and something outside it

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I'm having trouble connecting a node inside of a `forest` tree diagram with some arbitrary text outside it.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1912/60686
\tikzstyle{na} = [shape=rectangle,inner sep=0pt,text depth=0pt]

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[A, name=A
    [B]
    [C
        [X, name=X]
        [Y]
    ]
]
\draw[-latex,dotted] (A) to[out=west,in=west] (X);
\end{forest}

\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikz\node[na](lorem){Lorem}; ipsum \tikz\node[na](abc){dolor}; sit \tikz\node[na](amet){amet};.

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \draw (X) to (abc);
    \draw[-latex] (lorem) to[out=south,in=south] (amet);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

The result of the above code unfortunately looks like this:

[image]

In other words, tikz can't seem to find the node `X`, so the line just trails off to nowhere instead of connecting the `X` node to the `abc` node. In order to demonstrate that connecting things works inside of *either* the diagram *or* the text, I drew a bunch of arrows there as well.

Putting the line `\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]` above `\begin{forest}` causes the various content boxes and drawings to appear all on different pages.

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174398/using-tikz-overlay-remember-picture-option-with-forest-trees helps. (And by the way, `\tikzstyle` is considered deprecated in favor of `\tikzset{stylename/.style={...}}`.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. TeX insists on drawing the path from the top node in the tree in that case, though, and I can't get the path to be drawn right in the MWE of the solution to that question either – the two sigmas at the top are errorneously connected instead.

Comment: I've just realized it works that way when compiling with pdfLaTeX, but not with XeLaTeX. I need the latter for Unicode support and everything, though.

Comment: Actually, I just tested as well, and for me it doesn't work at all. I get `! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.` I have an up-to-date TeX Live 2016, perhaps there have been some changes in `forest` in the time since that question was asked and answered. Anyway, I know next to nothing about `forest`, but there are certainly other users around here that know quite a lot, so there's probably a good chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so for completeness' sake, this is my own improvement over [cfr's helpful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339896/60686), taking into account the workaround in the [comments to a previous question on basically the same topic by Stefan Müller](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229500/60686). The workaround mentioned there and employed here is unfortunately only alluded to, basically, but not given an example of.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, tikzmark, arrows.meta}

% WORKAROUND:    
% Definition copied from /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf-via-dvi.def
% Compare https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229500 and comments!
\makeatletter
\def\pgfsys@hboxsynced#1{%
  {%
    \pgfsys@beginscope%
    \setbox\pgf@hbox=\hbox{%
      \hskip\pgf@pt@x%
      \raise\pgf@pt@y\hbox{%
        \pgf@pt@x=0pt%
        \pgf@pt@y=0pt%
        \special{pdf: content q}%
        \pgflowlevelsynccm% 
        \pgfsys@invoke{q -1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm}%
        \special{pdf: content -1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm q}% translate to original coordinate system
        \pgfsys@invoke{0 J [] 0 d}% reset line cap and dash
        \wd#1=0pt%
        \ht#1=0pt%
        \dp#1=0pt%
        \box#1%
        \pgfsys@invoke{n Q Q Q}%
      }%
      \hss%
    }%
    \wd\pgf@hbox=0pt%
    \ht\pgf@hbox=0pt%
    \dp\pgf@hbox=0pt%
    \pgfsys@hbox\pgf@hbox%
    \pgfsys@endscope%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A, name=A
    [B]
    [C
      [\subnode{x}{X}, name=X]
      [Y]
    ]
  ]
  \draw [-Latex,dotted] (A) to[out=west,in=west] (X);
\end{forest}

Lo\tikzmark{lorem}rem ipsum do\tikzmark{abc}lor sit am\tikzmark{amet}et.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [-Latex, red] (x) [out=-75, in=110]to ([yshift=1.5ex]{pic cs:abc});
    \draw [-Latex] ({pic cs:lorem}) to[out=south,in=south] ({pic cs:amet});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This should successfully compile with `xelatex` (for Unicode support) under TeXLive 2016:

[image: Compilation of MWE with workaround definition]

Comment: Very useful! (+1)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I missed this one. Would have made my life over the past years much simpler. =:-) Shouldn't this fix go to the main tex distributions?

Comment: @StefanMüller It looks like there's work going on: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/353. FWIW, putting e.g. an AVM in a \node{} next to the tree and solely relying on \tikzmark{} doesn't make the copied-definition hack obsolete, either.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with using `\tikzmark` inside a `forest` tree is that you are nesting `tikzpicture` environments, which occasionally works but should never be relied on and should always be avoided (unless you really know what you're doing and are happy to keep all the itsy-bitsy pieces when it breaks).

Fortunately, `tikzmark` provides `\subnode{}` for such cases.

```
  [A, name=A
    [B]
    [C
      [\subnode{x}{X}, name=X]
      [Y]
    ]
  ]
```

This solves the problem.

[image: node-to-node text-to-text node-to-text]

One thing to remember here is that Forest uses a special coordinate system `forest cs`. However, you can only access this within a `forest` environment or `\Forest` macro. This seems to be true even if the starred macro, `\Forest*`, is used which allows you to access nodes outside the current group e.g. from within *another* `forest` environment or `Forest[*]` macro.

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  [A, name=A
    [B]
    [C
      [\subnode{x}{X}, name=X]
      [Y]
    ]
  ]
  \draw [-Latex,dotted] (A) to[out=west,in=west] (X);
\end{forest}

Lo\tikzmark{lorem}rem ipsum do\tikzmark{abc}lor sit am\tikzmark{amet}et.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw [-Latex, red] (x) [out=-75, in=110]to ([yshift=1.5ex]{pic cs:abc});
    \draw [-Latex] ({pic cs:lorem}) to[out=south,in=south] ({pic cs:amet});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This indeed compiles with the desired result (thank you!), but only in pdflatex, not in xelatex :( I'll be looking further into that, e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229500/60686

Comment: @Jipí It works with `lualatex`.

Comment: Did you try the workaround described in the comments? Might be worth looking up the bug report and trying to improve it.

Comment: Yes, that works. In the bug report (https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/354/), Stefan Müller writes that he would contact the author of `tikzmark` directly. Apparently nothing has happened since?

Comment: @Jipí Isn't it a PGF bug?

Comment: @Jipí The problem is that the bug report is a very poor one because the example nests `tikzpicture`s which isn't expected to work. What is needed, I think, is an example using `\subnode` at least, and showing that the problem is in the PGF driver by demonstrating the workaround. Ideally, the example would not use `tikzmark` at all, but I don't know how easy that would be to do.

Comment: So would it be helpful to crosspost my solution below to the bug report I linked above, too, since it actually *states* the workaround mentioned in the other thread?

Comment: What is really needed is a better minimal example. But I think that will be hard here, so I would link here and include your code there, noting what you've added to make it work specifically in XeLaTeX and where the definition is from.