# How to link different trees with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

This is my current scenario: I have two trees with defined with `forest`, side by side, each one inside a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
[a
  [b
    [c]
    [d]
  ]
   [e,draw,dashed]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
[f
  [g]
  [,phantom]
  [h,tikz={\node [draw,dashed,fit=() (!1) (!l)] {};}
    [i]
    [j]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Quack]

So far, so good!

Now I want to link node `e` from tree 1 with node `h` from tree 2. Now things started to get frustrating. I tried to give these nodes a proper name and apply `remember picture`, but it seems the names are not persisted between environments (it's worth mentioning that Alan provided an alternative solution by using only one tree mimicking two trees [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40244763#40244763); it solves my immediate problem, but I am still interested in seeing how a proper link would be).

My searches in TeX.sx indicated `tikzmark` as the easiest, most direct solution, so here we go. I found a promising solution by Adam Liter here:

[Using tikz overlay / remember picture option with forest trees](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174398/using-tikz-overlay-remember-picture-option-with-forest-trees)

Sadly, it seems there were some updates in perhaps everything in the TeX world that made my trees collapse into a accident of nightmarish proportions and whatnot:

```
Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.
```

The answer provided in the linked question does not work anymore, and neither does my code. So I beseech your wisdom! Tying a yellow ribbon 'round the old `forest` tree seems simple enough, however, my plans of creating a potential hammock between two independent `forest` trees have been shattered. `:)`

Does anybody have an idea of what is broken?

Comment: +1 Thanks for bringing this up. `:)` I've also updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: It would be simpler if you wanted to draw a line from h to where e would be if e's root was where h's root is. *That* Forest can do by itself. I think it would be good if there was a more integrated way of doing this, but `\subnode` is the best I can think of right now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use \subnode:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
[a
  [b
    [c,name=c]
    [d,name=d]
  ]
   [\subnode{marke}{e},draw,dashed]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{forest}
[f
  [g]
  [,phantom]
  [\subnode{markh}{h},name=h,tikz={\node [draw,dashed,fit=() (!1) (!l)] {};}
    [i]
    [j]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[green](marke.east)--(markh.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that *is* very impressive! Thank you, Ulrike!

Comment: Do you understand in detail why `\subnode` works? (Unfortunately your nice trick no longer works very smoothly once the nodes become more involved, like going over two lines.)

Answer (score 17):

No idea what is broken, but is this workaround OK?

Essentially, use one `forest` for both trees, with the root as a `phantom` node. The `s sep` determines the distance between the two trees.

I don't know if/how nodes are named in `forest`, so I gave the `e` and `h` nodes an `alias` that I used in the `\draw` at the end.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[,phantom,s sep=3cm
[a
  [b
    [c]
    [d]
  ]
   [e,draw,dashed,alias=e]
]
[f
  [g]
  [,phantom]
  [h,alias=h,tikz={\node [draw,dashed,fit=() (!1) (!l)] {};}
    [i]
    [j]
  ]
]
]
\draw [-stealth](e) to[bend right] (h.west);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `+1` It is indeed a nice workaround! `:)` I am interested in seeing why my original attempt with `tikzmark` (as well as some answers in the site that make use of it) had failed. For now, thank you very much! Let us wait a bit. `:)`